# Can List-group-items from bootstrap be ordered?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to sort by class.  I am using bootstrap list-group-items and setting a class danger or success depending if it has messages or not.  The way the database is makes it pretty hard to do it and the flow of the program makes it hard as well.  This would make life a lot easier if there was a way to sort items by class.

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "get_name.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
                funcName: "getBadge",
                userId: user_id,
                techId: techId,
                chat_id: chatId,
            },
            datatype: "JSON",
            success: function(result) {
                var temp = result.split("_");
                if(temp[0]>0){
                    $("#" + techId).addClass("list-group-item-danger");
                }else{
                    $("#" + techId).addClass("list-group-item-success");
                }

                $("#" + techId + " .badge").html(temp[0]);
            },
```

Comment: Could you post the code that's being run for which you're running the `success` handler? Am having some trouble understanding what you're doing.

Comment: @shotor I am calling an ajax call that makes a group list item and then the ajax call you see is me adding the bootstrap badge to the item.  This is for an instant messaging application

Comment: Right, so you're retrieving the messages and adding them one by one. You don't have a handler when ALL messages have been added, and that's probably not even possible in your case. So the only way I see that you could sort these messages is to define a `sortMessages` function, and running it at the end of each `success` handler to re-sort the messages based on their classes - if you need some assistance, let me know and I'll write up an example - One problem: I don't see in your code anywhere where you actually add a "new" message to the page

Comment: @shotor Thank you I will give it a try and give you a message back in an hour or so.